# MediaElementPlayer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have an issue when I try to initialize the player...this is my init code:

```
var showFullScreenVideo = function(url) {

                    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1', {
        pluginPath: '/js/renderers',
        enablePluginDebug:true,
        success: function (media) {
            console.log('media: '+media);

        },
        error : function(mediaElement) {
            console.log('medialement problem is detected: %o', mediaElement);
        }
    });
    console.log(player);

    player.setSrc(url.replace('&amp;', '&'));
    player.load();
    if (!mejs.Features.isiOS && !mejs.Features.isAndroid) {
        player.play();
    }
};
```

neither of the "console.log" statements in either success or error methods doesn't fire...
the "console.log(player)" statement below the init call fires and outputs below, but when it comes to the setSrc call it errors out with the error also shown on the screenshot...

anyone has any ideas? URL of the page in question is: [http://dev.wasup.si/sharksup-lemon-shark-100-2018-pid322-subID0#](http://dev.wasup.si/sharksup-lemon-shark-100-2018-pid322-subID0) -> click on "VIDEI"

[image: capture]

Comment: thanks for the input, but it does not make any difference

Comment: Are you calling `player.setSrc()` anywhere else? It certainly looks like it should be defined where it's referenced here...

Comment: no...just there...I even renamed it to a different variable name to avoid any confusion but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a senior moment from me....when calling the init function I entered as selector "#player1", when it should have been just "player1"...

Sorry to waste everbody's time but I honestly didn't see it...when I took a break and came back to it just now it immediately occured to me.